# Existing Ruby on Rails web app on Heroku (PostgreSQL), Devise authentication, need to add Rails API for mobile backed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mobile, devise

I have an existing RoR web application which currently uses Devise for authentication.

I am planning on adding API functionality in one manner or another for a mobile backend.

Would you recommend adding API functionality to the web application and using JWT, for example, to enable mobile authentication. Alternatively, would you have two separate applications, a web application and an API, sharing the same Postgres instance on Heroku?

I see pros and cons both ways, but it would seem to me that separating it into two applications would outweigh adding API functionality to the web app. Perhaps, it would make most sense to start over with just an API and add mobile app client and web application client functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new API only backend might be easier at first, but you would have to copy all your app logic in the models over and keeping both sides up to date will be a pain. You can do it in the same rails app if you namespace the new API so that all calls are under a `/api_v1` or something like that. [Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/adding-versions-rails-api/) is an article that show how you can have different versions of your API.

JWTs for authentication is a great way of doing it and Devise can support them by adding a gem like [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) since adding a route and handling the creation and updating of tokens by yourself is a lot of work.

For the API itself you might want to consider using [JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/) with the [jsonapi-rails](https://github.com/jsonapi-rb/jsonapi-rails) gem or [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) with the [graphql](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby) gem. This way when someone wants to use your API they can use an adapter for their framework that can talk to that kind of API and not have to worry about the structure of what it returns. There are adapters for both APIs that work with Andrioid, IOS, Ember, React, and all other major frontend frameworks.

Comment: It sounds like it makes more sense to do it via the rails app and add the API. Will try this.

Comment: :) good luck, I recommend you read up on json:api and graphql and decide which is better for you before starting.